# Using .delay() in a custom queue in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an infinite loop whereby an element has a notice that rotates in a pattern, with delays, in a custom queue. I've been bashing my head against this for a while now, no matter what I try, it always executes the code without the required delays. Any light you can shed on this would be most helpful. I cannot use the 'fx' queue as I have another element that needs to animate in step with the notices.

Thanks in advance!

```
$.fn.queueNotice = function(string, delay) {
  this.queue('notice', function(next) {
    this.html(string).delay(delay);
    next();
  });
  return this;
}

var notices = setInterval(noticeLoop, 0);

function noticeLoop() {
  $("div").queueNotice("Notice 1", 1000)
          .queueNotice("Notice the second", 3000)
          .queueNotice("A third notice", 5000)
          .queueNotice("A fourth notice", 1000)
          .dequeue('notice');
}
```

Comment: Try `setTimeout()`

Comment: @Piterden I have, I couldn't make it work. Could you show me how you would craft that loop?

Comment: `.delay(delay)` is asynchronous, so `next();` is called immediately

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried `.queueNotice("Notice 1").delay(1000)` as well, with the same result

Comment: yep, because `.delay` is asynchronous, so `next` gets called immediately

Comment: @JaromandaX okay cool, thanks for the clarification, how would you achieve the desired result? :)

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery docs:

> .delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Interestingly, your code does not work at all, because your `this` isn't what you think it is - I've fixed that for you as well

```js
$.fn.queueNotice = function(string, delay) {
  var self = this;
  this.queue('notice', function(next) {
    self.html(string);
    setTimeout(next, delay);
  });
  return this;
}

function noticeLoop() {
  $("div").queueNotice("Notice 1", 1000)
    .queueNotice("Notice the second", 3000)
    .queueNotice("A third notice", 5000)
    .queueNotice("A fourth notice", 1000)
    .dequeue('notice');
}
noticeLoop();
setInterval(noticeLoop, 11000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

</div>
```

I've made it so noticeloop only runs once (because it's annoying otherwise :p)

Comment: does it? what is the exception?

Comment: this doesn't have html method

Comment: really? The original code seems to ( though, it should not - but then, your code isn't any better at all in that regard)

Comment: Well, the original code supposedly works, just doesn't delay _ I must admit I took the OP at his word - your code, `this` is `window` ... so your code does not work either

Comment: Yes my bad, I edited the code for ease of reading. But fixing this exception still does not give the desired delay in the steps of the sequence.

Comment: I've fixed it now

Comment: console log `this`. It is not window inside function () {}

Comment: You could just use the arrow function

Comment: Because I call the function on the element I want to change, `this` is correct. The element updates, with the desired string, but the required delay is not respected, and it just rapid fires the changes.

Comment: sorry, @DaveMoTron thought you were the other guy :p can you show *working code* since you said your code *works* (other than the delay)\

Comment: @JaromandaX yep check this out: https://codepen.io/davemotron/pen/gBGZGv?editors=1111

Comment: right, so you use self like I do in the answer - does the answer work for you?

Comment: @JaromandaX it works in my project the same way it works in that codepen, changes work, but they rotate without delay

Comment: `var notices = setInterval(noticeLoop, 0);` see that ... you call noticeLoop continuously!!! each one just runs over the top of the others - look at this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdwMxp?editors=1111 and notice the difference

Comment: What you can do is `setInterval(noticeLoop, 11000); noticeLoop();` instead of the `setTimeout` I've put in

Comment: I've updated the answer ... note that the interval is 11 seconds, even though the times add up to 10 seconds - I haven't quite figured that out :p

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.fn.queueNotice = function (string, delay) {
  this.queue('notice', function (next) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $(this).html(string);
      next();
    }, delay);
  });
  return this;
}

var notices = setInterval(noticeLoop, 10000);

function noticeLoop() {
  $("div").queueNotice("Notice 1", 1000)
    .queueNotice("Notice the second", 3000)
    .queueNotice("A third notice", 5000)
    .queueNotice("A fourth notice", 1000)
    .dequeue('notice');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think you want the `$(this).html(string);` inside the setTimeout - that changes what the code does :p